# Proof on characteristic values

Tags: linear-algebra

> If $V$ is a vectorial space of finite dimension over a field $F$ and T is a invertible linear operator over the field $V$, also, say that $\lambda \in F^*$
>
> Prove that $\lambda$ is a characteristic value of T if and only if $\frac{1}{\lambda} $ is a characteristic value of $T^{-1}$

For the first direction I assume that $\lambda$ is a characteristic value of T, i.e, $\exists v \in V- ${$0$}  such that $Tv = \lambda v$
What we have to prove is that  $\exists w \in V- ${$0$}  such that $T^{-1}w = \frac{1}{\lambda} w$

I guess the other direction is similar, but I have no clue how to prove this, how can I use the inversible hypothesis?

Comment: "What we have to prove is that [..]" -- Should it not be $T^{-1}$ at the end of this line?

Comment: You're right! My bad

Comment: For the converse, you want to assume that $\lambda^{-1}$ is an eigenvalue (characteristic value) of $T^{-1}$, and show that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$. Try writing down the equation you get from the assumption here, and then apply $T$ to both sides and rearrange.

Answer (score 1):

$Tv = \lambda v \iff v=\lambda T^{-1}v \iff \frac{1}{\lambda}v=T^{-1}v $.